# “between" vs. “on" for days of the week

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct in this sentence? Should it be:

> **between** Sunday and Wednesday

or:

> **on** Sunday and Wednesday

The question is from a practice test:

> They decided to study ________ Sunday and Wednesday ________ the morning
>
> A. between/in
>   B. from/to
>   C. on/in
>   D. by/at

My English teacher says (A) is the right choice, but I picked (C).

Comment: Without further context, both A and C work. It’s a matter of opinion which is ‘correct’.

Comment: C is a lot less ambiguous. between dates is always tricky does is it inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: I would choose C as the most natural and unambiguous. There's nothing wrong with A in terms of syntax, but its meaning is a bit unclear. What's "correct" depends on the intended communication.

Comment: Please avoid using scanned pictures when you want to include sample text. It may be easier for you to upload, but it’s harder for us to read and analyze. Also, for more formatting tips, see our [Contributor’s Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners).

Comment: It would be grammatical to say between but not usual. The criminals committed the act sometime between Wednesday and Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I'm C all the way.  This option sets 2 days with a start time for each day.

Option A, "They decided to study between Sunday and Wednesday in the morning."
is very unclear.  The only way it makes sense to me is that they are indecisive on which day the will study in the morning.  If the intent is to study on all the days between Sunday and Wednesday, a native speaker would say "They decided to study from Sunday to Wednesday in the morning."  I'd more likely say "They decided to study in the mornings starting Sunday through Wednesday."  For a native take on the indecisive option, "They decided to study sometime in the morning between Sunday and Wednesday."

Answer (score 0):

> They decided to study ________ Sunday and Wednesday ________ the
>   morning
>
> A. between/in
>   B. from/to
>   C. on/in
>   D. by/at

This is one of those questions where correctness isn't exactly the way to look at this. Depending on the intended meaning, either A or C could be valid, but for most of the possible meanings, a slight tweak makes it clearer.

> Case 1: The question means that they decided to study each morning, for each day between Sunday and Wednesday.

In this case, the answer would be A (between/in), however adding a single letter would make this more obvious. Normally, with this sentence structure (no rearranging or changing words), saying "They decided to study between Sunday and Wednesday in the mornings" would be most correct. Note the pluralization of "morning" indicating that it's the morning of each day in the specified range.

> Case 2: The question means that they decided to study during the morning of both Sunday and Wednesday. In other words, exactly 2 study sessions on those two exact days.

In this case, the answer would be C (on/in), but yet again, in dealing with more than 1 morning, pluralizing it to "mornings" would clarify significantly. Additionally, it would be even better to replace "in the morning(s)" with either "each morning" or "both mornings", as this further reduces ambiguity.

> Case 3: The question means that they decided to study *one time* on some yet-undetermined day between Sunday and Wednesday.

This case is the least likely and requires the most work to make it sounds right, but is still possible with A (between/in) as the answer. The easiest solution is to add the words "some time" right after "study".